Settings won't launch on 22.04LTS desktop
Several questions have been asked on this topic but none solved my issue.  System has been working fine for a long time.  Shut it off for a few days and when I restarted it, I had several problems.  The most obvious is that the settings function won't launch.  Everything seems to more or less work ok although I no longer have audio.  That's how I noticed that I could not launch settings. Any related command gives the below undefined symbol complaint.  There was an identical question where the OP tried numerous things to fix this and none helped.  No possible solutions were offered.  I'd like to upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS but obviously don't want to do that until this is resolved.
Trying to launch settings from the GUI or CLI returns the following error:
symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2
I upgraded everything prior to posting this question.
This could well be a very easy fix.  Hoping someone offers a solution.
gnome-control-center --verbose
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2

The following ran without error:
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center

locate gnome-control-center.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop

apt list -a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
Listing... Done
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2.44.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy 2.36.0-2ubuntu1 amd64

libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.44.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy 2.36.0-2ubuntu1 i386

One answer recommend the following which did not resolve my issue:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa

Gnome otherwise appears to be working fine.
Many related questions focus on the video driver as the culprit.  This is the configuration I am running:
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:149 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df500000-df53ffff memory:df540000-df55ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


Apparently the latest AMD drivers (at least for my Radeon 530 video card) do not work on Ubuntu 22.04.  This seems odd since this card has been installed for a VERY long time.  But the following fix definitely worked:
amdgpu-uninstall

When I tried to reinstall the drivers this is the error I got:
.
.
.
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,284 B of archives.
After this operation, 38.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pro-pin 20.45-1188099 [6,284 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-pin.
(Reading database ... 330686 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pro-pin_20.45-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-pin (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-pin (20.45-1188099) ...
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-pin (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-pro-pin package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-pro-pin
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: Unable to install pin package.
This driver may not support the running operating system.

This is the latest version I could find.  If there is a newer one for Ubuntu 22.04 and ideally 24.04 I would be most grateful fir the link to it.
amdgpu-pro-20.45-1188099-ubuntu-20.04

